# How to apply the html tags to Uilabel text

Tags: iphone

Iam developing one application.In that iam using the uilabels.And my problem is i need to apply the html effects to that label data.For example i need to add the anchor tag to that text.Then i need to use the anchor tag for that text.So please tell me how to use that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading your comment below, do you mean something like [this](http://blog.stormyprods.com/2009/10/simple-scrolling-uilabel-for-iphone.html)? You definitely don't need to use UIWebView for a marquee effect. Have you searched the net? There are many examples of slightly different effects you can achieve very easily with UILabel.

Answer (score 0):

[`UILabel`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html) only support's plain text. I gues your best bed is to use [`UIWebView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) or go directly to [`CoreText`](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/CoreText_Programming/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: In my page contain the 10 labels.They are printed using for loop.I need to scroll the label text like as marquee effect in html.

Comment: use UIWebView with loading HTML string. you can create it very easily

Comment: How can i use the webview instead of uilabel.